# Retrieving values from php?

Tags: php, c++, response

I am developing in C++ and is trying to learn some php.
I was wondering, I know I can take values from netsend (url request) like 'index.php?user=myUser' and so on. How can i use netsend to retrieve the same value, user? Is it even possible?
Sending a request, how do I determine what is the 'response' ?

Thank you,
Martol1ni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, and it's easy.  Just use the PHP _$GET[] variable:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

The "response" is whatever your PHP program returns.  It's usually an HTML page.  But it could just as easily be a word, a number, a line of text ... or an XML document or a JSON object.  It's totally up to you.

Here's a good tutorial (one of many you can find on the Web):

http://phptutorial.info/

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['user']; or $_REQUEST['user']
```

Response is what ever u output.

Comment: Let's say I am posting index.php?user=myUser . I want a response from the PHP to where the request came from, like returning true or something. Possible?

Comment: yes, you can use get_header() and do comparison of what every variable you want and return something. Here is a reference to header info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: Probably good to look at $_SERVER for more server information, such as requested URL, or you localhost info.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET , $_POST Or $_REQUEST

Sample usage

```
$getValue = $_GET['query'];
$getValue = $_POST['query'];
$getValue = $_REQUEST['query'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php